# OpenWhisk PHP action showing error as output

Tags: php, serverless, openwhisk

I am trying to create an openWhisk PHP action using PHP language.
I have created a PHP file with a **hello.php** file with below code,

```
<?php
function main(array $args) : array
{
    $name = $args["name"] ?? "stranger";
    $greeting = "Hello $name!";
    echo $greeting;
    return ["greeting" => $greeting];
}
```

Now I try to run command using CLI with PHP,

**wsk action create helloPHP hello.php --kind php:7.3**

I have installed PHP 7.3 and run above command in PHP 7.3
When I run above command got an error like below,

```
error: Unable to create action 'helloPHP': The request content was malformed:
kind 'php:7.3' not in Set(nodejs:10-fat, nodejs:10, nodejs:8, nodejs, blackbox, sequence, nodejs:6) (code FsBP1CzMYjOc7W1HMXBHbK0YabJtCFkN)
Run 'wsk --help' for usage.
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the error message the runtime PHP 7.3 is not installed on your openwhisk deployment. You can edit the runtimes manifest and redeploy the controller and invoker to add the runtime. Here is an example runtime manifest that adds the PHP kind for this version of the runtime https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/8cd10bb09d64c1bc2638f05d1fb8dadb24b7f36e/ansible/files/runtimes.json#L223-L236.

More details here about the manifest. https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/actions-new.md#the-runtimes-manifest.

Redeploying the whole system, or being more surgical are plausible options - it depends on how you manage your deployment.

Comment: I run command with, wsk action create helloPHP hello.php --kind php:7.3